# Is there a way to jail in Javascript, so that the DOM isn't visible

Tags: javascript, dom, scripting, restriction

I would really like to provide the user some scripting capabilities, while not giving it access to the more powerful features, like altering the DOM. That is, all input/output is tunneled thru a given interface. Like a kind of restricted javacsript.

Example:
If the interface is `checkanswer(func)`
this are allowed:

```
checkanswer( function (x,y)={
   return x+y;
}
```

but these are not allowed:
<strike>`alert(1)`

`document.write("hello world")`

`eval("alert()")`</strike>

EDIT: what I had in mind was a simple language that was implemented using javascript, something like http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=92

Comment: Where do you want to run the scripts? In the browser or on the server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(**Edit** This answer relates to your pre-edit question. Don't know of any script languages implemented using Javascript, although I expect there are some. For instance, at one point someone wrote BASIC for Javascript (used to have a link, but it rotted). The remainder of this answer is therefore pretty academic, but I've left it just for discussion, illustration, and even cautionary purposes. Also, I definitely agree with [bobince's points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673695/is-there-a-way-to-jail-in-javascript-so-that-the-dom-isnt-visible/2673805#2673805) — don't do this yourself, use the work of others, such as [Caja](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caja_%28programming_language%29).)

If you allow any scripting in user-generated content, be ready for the fact you'll be entering an arms race of people finding holes in your protection mechanisms and exploiting them, and you responding to those exploits. I think I'd probably shy away from it, but you know your community and your options for dealing with abuse. So if you're prepared for that:

Because of the way that Javascript does symbol resolution, it seems like it should be possible to evaluate a script in a context where `window`, `document`, `ActiveXObject`, `XMLHttpRequest`, and similar don't have their usual meanings:

```
// Define the scoper
var Scoper = (function() {
    var rv = {};

    rv.scope = function(codeString) {
        var window,
            document,
            ActiveXObject,
            XMLHttpRequest,
            alert,
            setTimeout,
            setInterval,
            clearTimeout,
            clearInterval,
            Function,
            arguments;
            // etc., etc., etc.

        // Just declaring `arguments` doesn't work (which makes
        // sense, actually), but overwriting it does
        arguments = undefined;

        // Execute the code; still probably pretty unsafe!
        eval(codeString);
    };

    return rv;;
})();

// Usage:
Scoper.scope(codeString);
```

(Now that uses the evil `eval`, but I can't immediately think of a way to shadow the default objects cross-browser without using `eval`, and if you're receiving the code as text anyway...)

But it **doesn't work**, it's only a partial solution (more below). The logic there is that any attempt within the code in `codeString` to access `window` (for instance) will access the local variable `window`, not the global; and the same for the others. Unfortunately, because of the way symbols are resolved, any property of `window` can be accessed with or without the `window.` prefix (`alert`, for instance), so you have to list those too. This could be a long list, not least because as [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) points out, IE dumps any DOM element with a name or an ID onto `window`. So you'd probably have to put all of this in its own iframe so you can do an end-run around *that* problem and "only" have to deal with the standard stuff. Also note how I made the `scope` function a property of an object, and then you *only* call it through the property. That's so that `this` is set to the `Scoper` instance (otherwise, on a raw function call, `this` defaults to `window`!).

But, as bobince points out, there are just so many different ways to get at things. For instance, this code in `codeString` successfully breaks the jail above:

```
(new ('hello'.constructor.constructor)('alert("hello from global");'))()
```

Now, *maybe* you could update the jail to make that specific exploit not work (mucking about with the `constructor` properties on all — *all* — of the built-in objects), but I tend to doubt it. And if you *could*, someone (like Bob) would just come up with a new exploit, like this one:

```
(function(){return this;})().alert("hello again from global!");
```

Hence the "arms race."

The only really thorough way to do this would be to have a proper Javascript parser built into your site, parse their code and check for illegal accesses, and only then let the code run. It's a lot of work, but if your use-case justifies it...

Comment: Plus of course every document object with an id/name gets dumped into `window` on IE... have fun filtering those out!

Comment: @bobince: *blech* Yeah, you'd probably have to combine the above with an iframe or something to handle those, so you "only" have to worry about the standard stuff, not the named/identified elements. (Updated answer with that, thanks, although it seems that actually letting users use Javascript *isn't* quite what he meant.)

Comment: And then there's `new Function('...')()` to escape local scope. This isn't blockable as you can grab a `constructor` to get a `Function`. And `arguments.caller` to script up the call stack; `arguments` may not be overwritable. And fiddling with object prototypes later used by the caller. And returning an object with a sabotaged `toString` or properties. And so on. To summarise: aaaaargh. :-)

Comment: @bobince: Arrgh is right. :-) You can shadow `Function` and `arguments` on Chrome, Firefox, and IE. I'm not following your `constructor` argument (you can get *a* function, but how does that let you get the `Function` constructor?). But I'm with you that this is a *lot* of work and, as I said at the outset, an arms race.

Comment: If you can get a function, you can get Function. So, to get around shadowing: `new ('hello'.constructor.constructor)('alert("hello from global")')`. Similarly, shadowing `arguments`, there's `(function(){ arguments.callee.caller.caller })()`... and so on. Arms race is right!

Comment: @bobince: Oh, too clever (the `.constructor.constructor` thing). (And for any doubters: I've tried it, and not surprisingly, he's absolutely right.)

Comment: w00w what a geek-off :D didn't mean to offend anyone just its hard to understand what you guys are talking about

Comment: @c0mrade: summary: JavaScript is very flexible and also very ugly. :-)

Comment: @c0mrade: I tried to make it clear in the actual answer. The comments here are definitely a bit geek-off. :-) And (to me) very valuable, thanks Bob. Yes, Javascript is very powerful, very flexible, and with that comes some trickiness. (I don't agree with Bob's "ugly" characterization, but tomatoes tomahtoes...)

Comment: Just for kicks now: `self` survives `Scoper` as a `window` reference. And naturally, `(function(){return this})()` -> `window`...

Comment: @bobince: LOL You're just having fun now, aren't you? :-) Re `self`, that's just another thing that needs shadowing. Whereas `(function(){return this;)()` is just yet another reason for my having added the statement that "...this **doesn't work**..." in the answer. ;-)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: Thanks, I've removed it. Now that your have rep >= 2000, you can directly remove rotted links.

Comment: @T.J. thanks, I'm fully aware of my edit privileges. I try to let people have a chance to fix it themselves - maybe they know of a mirror or something. If you hadn't responded I would've removed it :)

Answer (score 5):

T.J. Crowder makes an excellent point about the "arms race." It's going to be *very* tough to build a watertight sandbox.

it's possible to override certain functions, though, quite easily.

Simple functions:

- [JavaScript: Overriding alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert)

And according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801258/redirect-document-write-from-javascript-script), even overriding things like `document.write` is as simple as

```
document.write = function(str) {}
```

if that works in the browsers you need to support (I assume it works in all of them), that may be the best solution.

Alternative options:

- Sandboxing the script into an IFrame on a different subdomain. It would be possible to manipulate its own DOM and emit alert()s and such, but the surrounding site would remain untouched. You may have to do this anyway, no matter which method(s) you choose
- Parsing the user's code using a white list of allowed functions. Awfully complex to do as well, because there are so many notations and variations to take care of.
- There are several methods to monitor the DOM for changes, and I'm pretty sure it's possible to build a mechanism that reverts any changes immediately, quite similar to Windows's DLL management. But it's going to be awfully complex to build and very resource-intensive.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. JavaScript is an extremely dynamic language with many hidden or browser-specific features that can be used to break out of any kind of jail you can devise.

Don't try to take this on yourself. Consider using an existing ‘mini-JS-like-language’ project such as [Caja](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caja_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: if the sandbox needs to be really secure, this is probably the only worthwhile way.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to process the user entered data and replace invalid mark-up based on a white list or black-list of allowed content.

Comment: but that's not exactly what I would like, because first of all, such parsing could be quite easily circumvented by using encoding. What I had in mind was a simple language that was interpreted by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way as Facebook did. They're preprocessing all the javascript sources, adding a prefix to all the names other than their own wrapper APIs'.

Answer (score 0):

I got another way: use google gears WorkerPool api
See this
http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_workerpool.html

> A created worker does not have access
>   to the DOM; objects like document and
>   window exist only on the main page.
>   This is a consequence of workers not
>   sharing any execution state. However,
>   workers do have access to all
>   JavaScript built-in functions. Most
>   Gears methods can also be used,
>   through a global variable that is
>   automatically defined:
>   google.gears.factory. (One exception
>   is the LocalServer file submitter,
>   which requires the DOM.) For other
>   functionality, created workers can ask
>   the main page to carry out requests.

Answer (score 0):

What about this pattern in order to implement a sandbox?

```
function safe(code,args)
{
    if (!args)
        args=[];
    return (function(){
    for (i in window) 
        eval("var "+i+";");
    return function(){return eval(code);}.apply(0,args);
    })();
}



ff=function()
{
    return 3.14;
}

console.log(safe("this;"));//Number
console.log(safe("window;"));//undefined
console.log(safe("console;"));//undefined
console.log(safe("Math;"));//MathConstructor
console.log(safe("JSON;"));//JSON
console.log(safe("Element;"));//undefined
console.log(safe("document;"));//undefined
console.log(safe("Math.cos(arguments[0]);",[3.14]));//-0.9999987317275395
console.log(safe("arguments[0]();",[ff]));//3.14
```

That returns:

```
Number
undefined
undefined
MathConstructor
JSON
undefined
undefined
-0.9999987317275395
3.14
```

Can you please provide an exploit suitable to attack this solution ? Just to understand and improve my knowledge, of course :)

THANKS!

Comment: Have you seen the selected answer, it has many exploits that will get the global object.

Answer (score 0):

This is now easily possible with sandboxed IFrames:

```js
var codeFunction = function(x, y) {
    alert("Malicious code!");
    return x + y;
}

var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.sandbox = "allow-scripts";
iframe.style.display = "none";
iframe.src = `data:text/html,
<script>
    var customFunction = ${codeFunction.toString()};
    window.onmessage = function(e) {
        parent.postMessage(customFunction(e.data.x, e.data.y), '*'); // Get arguments from input object
    }
</script>`;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.onload = function() {
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({ // Input object
        x: 5,
        y: 6
    }, "*");
}
window.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data); // 11
    document.body.removeChild(iframe);
}
```