# How to have javascript that can't use window.* methods

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a new project called "Burn". This will be similar to Khan Academy's Computer Science program. How could I have a "private" JavaScript context that cannot use any methods other that those specified?

Comment: Hi user, I'd suggest editing your post to clarify *why* you want to do this. At the minimum, it satisfies curiosity, and at most, it may give answerers information that is essential in giving you a good answer. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @jmort253 Actually he did include that information ("This will be similar to Khan Academy's Computer Science program")

Comment: @Doorknob - Okay, perhaps. But still, a little more context would make this a more complete, standalone question and not drive users in the other direction, *away* from Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Previously asked, and it's impossible: T. J. Crowder's answer to "[Is there a way to jail in Javascript, so that the DOM isn't visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673695/is-there-a-way-to-jail-in-javascript-so-that-the-dom-isnt-visible)" explains how any such context can be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IIFE` (immediatelyinvoked function expression) and write your code in it. You can redefine `window` object in that context so you cannot access other methods on window object.

```
(function (window){
    //code and other functions here
    // here window is undefined
})();
```

But I am not sure why you'd want that.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jHNpt/)

Comment: That would disallow `window.open` but it doesn't say anything about disallowing `open` (think about scope rules, `open` is already in scope).  I actually thought it might work, too, until I played with JsFiddle and realized what was happening.  I wonder if, though, with some of the newer flavors of ECMAScript if there isn't some variation of this that might work?  I dunno.

Comment: OK. I'll add it to my project. Thanks, Umair!

Comment: of course, I suppose there is the option of adding *all* of those `window.things` as parameters to your function. It might work, but *ugh*.

Comment: To prevent access, you need to create local variables to shadow all the standard window properties **and** run in strict mode, otherwise it's trivial to access the global/window object regardless of whether a local *window* variable has been created to shadow it. Do `for..in` on `window`, there are a lot of properties and methods.

Comment: @RobG: with exception of using `new Function`, how would you go about declaring names of variables in a `for-in` loop?

Comment: @RobG I have added link to jsFiddle